# Importing Brushes in 2.79 on Mac

Tags: add-on

I have tried to look at other posts on how to do this. I don't seem to have an import brushes option in User Preferences>Add Ons. I see where others have had a similar problem and it was suggested a python script was offered to fix this. I am not quite knowledgeable with coding and such. No idea how to add script. Would love to have some of these free brushes for Blender I've seen posted. Any help would be appreciated. 
Blender 2.79, MacOS versoin 10.14.6 (18G87), Intel Core i5, Graphics Radeon Pro 580 8 GB

Comment: Thank you. You were extremely helpful. That worked. Thanks for your time and efforts to help out a fellow Blender artist.

Comment: Converted to answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Brushes are considered the same as any other part of Blender comparable to objects and materials - they are 'imported' through the Append function. If you have a brush(es) stored in a file, you press Append under File and then navigate to the file containing them. Select the ones you want, and confirm to append into your scene - then you should be able to find them in your current file. Check them to be Fake User if you want them to stay in the file after close and reopen.